# socket.io try to listen to default apache port

Tags: node.js, socket.io, port

In my Node.js script, I set socket.io to listen on port 8080:

```
client = require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets);
```

Then I can connect with `io.connect('http://.../8080')`.

But why, in the firefox/chrome consoles, I see multiple GET requests on port 80?
Like these :

```
GET http://.../socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1408319587655-58
GET http://.../socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1408319592695-59
GET http://.../socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1408319597750-60
```

Those links are working with port 8080.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `io.connect('http://...:8080')` and not `io.connect('http://.../8080')` ?

Comment: Oops! It was that. Thanks.     Sorry for this useless question.